# Unable to remove punctuations from some columns, while it work fine for other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-preprocessing

I am trying to use a punctuation removal function and it worked fine for some columns but for few columns it just give the error as the column name.

```
def remove_punctuations(text):
for punctuation in string.punctuation:
    text = text.replace(punctuation, '')
return text

dataset['Info'] = dataset['Info'].apply(remove_punctuations)
dataset['Message'] = dataset['Message'].apply(remove_punctuations)
dataset['Target'] = dataset['Target'].apply(remove_punctuations)
dataset['command'] = dataset['command'].apply(remove_punctuations)
```

for the last run it gives me an error.

[image]

Comment: check dataset.columns to knok columns names

Comment: what is the output of `list(dataset.columns)`?

Comment: ['abort_testbench_on_crash      ',
 'code_coverage                 ',
 'coli_port                     ',
 'command                       ',
 'command_line                  ',
 'coverage_filter               ',
 'enabled_crash_traces          ',
 'lat_log_mode                  ',]

Answer (score 0):

The `KeyError` here basically says that you don't have column by the name `command` in your data frame. Is the `Command` with capital C?

Comment: nope, the command is with small c